# How to generate .h files for embedded app using java android app

Tags: java, java-native-interface, header-files, javac

I am working on an android app, this app reads the data from an XML file and then based on the data, it performs some functionality. Now, I want to save a subset of data from the app to a header file, in such a way that if we import the created header file we can perform the functionality associated with the subset of that particular data in another application.

I want to use .h file so that I can reuse the same file for another embedded application as well. Obviously I need to write a parser for that.

Any suggestion will be appreciated in this regard

Comment: This question could not be more vague if you tried. Are you asking how to generate a text file from Android code that can be parsed as a C header? What kind of data should it include? How do you plan to export this header file to your other applications?

Comment: Yes a text file would fulfil the requirements. 
Mainly data consists of bunch of variable and their values.

Comment: Okay, so your question is "how do I generate a file in Android". That is not very different from Java, except you have to jump through some hoops to store your file on the SD card (or implement a provider but that seems overkill for one file). As for the choice of serialization format, you can use anything from Android's Parcelable to Java's Serializable to more common formats like JSON or Protobuf.